# How can I manage the Outlook "always enable" add-ins list proactively?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, outlook-addin

In Outlook (I am using Outlook 2016), if Outlook detects a COM add-in problem (usually the add-in caused Outlook to be slow to start) it automatically disables the add-in. However, you can go to File -> Info -> "Slow and Disabled COM Add-ins" and re-enable the add-in, adding it to the "always enable" list. It will then not be disabled by Outlook in the future. This could be described as a "reactive" action, as we are reacting to the problem.

However, if I want to add an add-in to the "always enable" list that Outlook has not tried to disable (i.e. "proactive" action) is there any way to do this? The "Slow and Disabled COM Add-ins" list only shows those add-ins that either Outlook has automatically disabled, or those it would have disabled but didn't because they were in the "always enable" list. It doesn't show those add-ins that Outlook has not (yet) had any problem with and allow me to add them to the "always enable" list.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled and also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2017/08/02/outlooks-slow-add-ins-resiliency-logic-and-how-to-always-enable-slow-add-ins/

Comment: @spikey_richie I am not an Outlook developer, I am an Outlook user. There are at least 4 registry keys mentioned here, like AddinList, DisabledItems, CrashingAddinList and DoNotDisableAddinList. Is this the only way to go, editing these four registry keys - there is no way to do this proactively in Outlook itself?

Comment: Not that I know of.